# one-thread blocking approach for socket tcp multi-client server

Tags: python, socket, tcp

my use-case (an home task to practice abstraction, exception handling, unitests) is regarding a message-queue with small-fixed-size client requests from **stdin** of such:

> 1. [ENQ] data  (insert json data to queue)
> 2. [DEQ]       (get latest in queue)
> 3. [STATUS]    (status of queue)
> 4. [STOP]      (stop server)
> 5. [EXIT]

Without any scalability demands, except that there could be multi-clients and command might be extended in future.

I know there could be **multiple approaches to handle multi-client-server model** - multi-threaded or select one and that there are existent frameworks (Twisted, gevant).
I have chosen to implement a simple socket-per-command approach with BLOCKING threads. one main server thread will serve each coming socket with a timeout. every-time a new request arrives - new socket_connection is open - server reads whole data, sends a response and socket is closed. Then server moves to the next socket_connection, eventually holding ONE socket-a-time in a while() loop.

**Pros for the approach are:**

1. Intention to practice on abstraction, exception handling, tests and not on 'the right' way to work with sockets.
2. Easy to code and handle command-per-connection and verify buffer is fully 'read' by server.

**Cons:**

1. Sending huge JSON data on ENQ might block server main thread for long period of time.
2. Not easy to extend / scale.
3. Overhead of open-close connection socket.
4. NO Concurrency.

**My questions are:**

1. Are best practices/design patterns used for this use-case? in terms of time of coding-time, complexity, performance, etc.
2. If so - how is the flow?
3. Are all cases taken care?
4. Exception handling?
5. **Is this approach better than select?** server now holds 2x sockets (master & client) and only takes care of one socket, client- creates and terminates it socket per each stdin-request. rather than Select() which holds multiple sockets per client and DOES NOT TERMINATE socket for the whole std-in connection.

**Server-side: accept a socket connection and send response:**

```
def serve_forever(self):
    # init socket
    self.socket = self.init_socket(self.connection_details)
    while not self._stop:
        # connect new client:
        conn, addr = self.socket.accept()
        conn.settimeout(Utils.TIMEOUT)
        self.logger.info("New client {} has arrived".format(conn.getpeername()))
        response = {}
        try:
            # read from socket:
            data = self.read(conn)
            self.logger.info("Read successfully data from client")
            if not data:
                break  # client disconnected while writing to socket
            # write response to socket:
            response = self.handle_request(Utils.json_decode(data))
            self.write(conn, Utils.json_encode(response))
            self.logger.info("Sent successfully {}".format(response))
        except (socket.timeout, SocketReadError, SocketWriteError) as e:
            self._handle_socket_err(response, e)
        finally:
            # close connection:
            self._close_connection(conn)
            self.logger.info("Closed client connection successfully")
    self.stop_server()
```

**Client-side: create a socket-per-command(request):**

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        # parse std_input
        in_read = input("Enter wanted command\n").split(" ", 1)
        if not Utils.validate_input(in_read):
            print("Wrong stdin command entered")
            continue
        # init new socket connection:
        self.connect()

        try:
            # send request to server:
            request = self.parse_command(in_read)
            self.write(self.socket, Utils.json_encode(request))
            self.logger.info("Client {} sent successfully command: {}".format(self._get_name(), request))

            # read response from server:
            response = Utils.json_decode(self.read(self.socket))
            self.logger.info("Client {} received successfully response {}".format(self._get_name(), response))
            self.close_connection()
        except (socket.timeout, SocketReadError, SocketWriteError) as e:
            self.logger.error("Exception occurred".format(e))
        else:
            if request.get("type") == "EXIT" or request.get("type") == "STOP":
                self.logger.info("Closing server and existing client stdin")
                exit()
```

**And simple handle_request (command) on server side:**

```
def handle_request(self, request: dict) -> dict:
    self.logger.debug("Handling request {}".format(request))

    command_type, payload, status_code = request.get("type"), request.get("payload"), StatusCode.OK
    if command_type == "ENQ":
        status_code, payload = self._handle_enq(payload)
    elif command_type == "DEQ":
        status_code, payload = self._handle_deq(payload)
    elif command_type == "DEBUG":
        status_code, payload = self._handle_debug(payload)
    elif command_type == "STAT":
        status_code, payload = self._handle_stat(payload)
    elif command_type == "STOP" or command_type == "EXIT":
        status_code, payload = self._handle_stop(payload)

    self.logger.debug("Finished handling request")
    response = self._create_response(status_code, command_type, payload)
    return response
```